# Delete registry keys that contain a given word

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I delete all keys under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt` that contain a given word in the key name?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: There is a program from DCSoft called RegEditx that can do this. I have used it a few times to change my user profile name, and to delete registry entries from uninstalled programs (their uninstallers almost never completely remove the program). Just keep in mind that some registry entries can't be deleted without changing ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell it could be as easy as:

```
$Search='given word'
Get-ChildItem "HKCU:Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/MenuExt"|
    Where Name -like "*$Search*"|
        Remove-Item -Confirm
```

Paste into PowerShell console Or ISE or save as file with extension .ps1 and execute with a path i.e. `.\scriptfilename.ps1`

Sample output:

```
PS> $Search = 'Google'
PS> Get-ChildItem "HKCU:Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/MenuExt"|
>>     Where Name -like "*$Search*"|
>>         Remove-Item -Confirm

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Remove Key" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\
Internet Explorer\MenuExt\Add to Google Photos Screensa&ver".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Comment: Thank you; but this does not appear to be supported in PS 2.0 on Windows 7.